# Copy a single file in MSBuild without using Exec or ItemGroup

Tags: msbuild, exec, itemgroup

Is there any way to do this?  I just need to copy a single file and thought there may be some syntax for the SourceFiles parameter of the Copy task that means you don't need to define an ItemGroup beforehand, I'd rather stick with ItemGroup than use Exec though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Copy files also takes a straight propertygroup as input:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SourceFile>Some file</SourceFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="$(SourceFile)" DestinationFolder="c:\"/>
```

Or even just a string

```
<Copy SourceFiles="Pathtofile" DestinationFolder="c:\"/>
```

Comment: This helped me in automating the creation of web.config file for a WCF Library Project hosted in IIS. :)

Comment: For copying a single file if you want to specify the full path including a new filename, there's a DestinationFile attribute you would use instead of DestinationFolder.

Answer (score 4):

Just put the single file name as the value for "SourceFiles".
Easy-Peezey.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapper" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <WorkingCheckout>.</WorkingCheckout>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapper">
        <CallTarget Targets="CopyItTarget" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CopyItTarget">
        <Copy SourceFiles="c:\windows\system.ini" DestinationFolder="$(WorkingCheckout)\"/>     
        <Error Condition="!Exists('$(WorkingCheckout)\system.ini')" Text="No Copy Is Bad And Sad" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: This is actually covered by the second part of James' answer above, thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I needed to do the same thing, and wanted to put some version information in the file name. Here is how I did it for a project in $(SolutionDir) that references an executable created by another project in another solution that I can easily express the path to:

```html
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(SolutionDir)..\bin\$(Configuration)\SomeExectuable.exe">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersions" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetName)-%(AssemblyVersions.Version)$(TargetExt)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="NewTargetPath" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath)" DestinationFiles="$(NewTargetPath)" />
  </Target>
```